# Defining “interval” using the notion of midpoint only

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

I am trying to characterize the continuum $\mathcal{C}$ using only the notion of midpoint, i.e. the operation $\mu : \mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ assigning to each pair of points the midpoint between them. I thought of defining “unbounded interval” as a set $I \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ such that $I$ as well as $\mathcal{C}\backslash I$ are closed under $\mu$. But is that even true?

My thoughts so far: If $I$ has the above property but is not an interval, then both $I$ and $\mathcal{C}\backslash I$ are dense in $\mathcal{C}$ and noncountable (it is easy to find an injection from one into the other)...

Note: The more general question whether it is possible to define "interval" or order in the above setting has now been answered [here (in the comment by Matt F.)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235490/characterizing-the-continuum-using-only-the-notion-of-midpoint) and the answer is no.

Comment: Does your closedness of $I$ under $\mu$ mean: for all $x,y\in I,\mu(x,y)\in I$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with the usual definition of $\mathbb R$ (and assuming choice), we can define a set $I$ that's not an unbounded interval, but for which both $I$ and $\mathbb R \setminus I$ are closed under taking midpoints. (I use $\mathbb R$ to refer to the usual notion of realnumberness to distinguish from $\mathcal C$ which you want to build from the ground up.)

Choose a Hamel basis for $\mathbb R$ as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$, and let $b$ be an element of that basis. Then define $I$ to be the set of all elements of $\mathbb R$ so that, when represented in this basis, the coefficient of $b$ is nonnegative.

If we do this, then both $I$ and $\mathbb R\setminus I$ are closed under midpoint. If $x, y \in \mathbb R$ and have $b$-coefficients $x_b, y_b$, then $\frac{x+y}{2}$ has $b$-coefficient $\frac{x_b+y_b}{2}$. So if $x_b, y_b \ge 0$, then $\frac{x_b+y_b}{2} \ge 0$, and if $x_b, y_b < 0$, then $\frac{x_b + y_b}{2} <0$.

It's also worth noting that if $I$ and $\mathbb R\setminus I$ are closed under midpoints, and $I$ is bounded from above, *then* $I$ is an unbounded interval. Let $x = \sup I$. For any $\epsilon>0$, there is some $y \in I$ with $y > x-\epsilon$. If we now take $z < x-2\epsilon$, then $2y-z > x$, so $2y-z \notin I$. So we must have $z \in I$, or else $\frac{z + (2y-z)}{2} = y \notin I$ would be a contradiction. Therefore $(-\infty, x-2\epsilon) \subseteq I$ for all $\epsilon$, and therefore their union, $(-\infty, x)$, is contained in $I$. So $I$ is either $(-\infty,x]$ or $(-\infty,x)$ depending on whether $x \in I$ or not.

Comment: That was quick! Unfortunately I don't know how to define “bounded (from above)“...

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting metric structure on these midpoints; such as as a weakened version of midpoint convexity.

Or just that the midpoint functions values exist in that appropriates, F(c/2+c1/2) exists in the structure somewhere between the c1 and c2 c1