# Characterizing the continuum using only the notion of midpoint

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Is it possible to categorically characterize the continuum using only the notion of midpoint? I assume some kind of Dedekind-cut-axiom will be necessary, but I don't know how to define order ([see my related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235427/defining-interval-using-the-notion-of-midpoint-only)).

Comment: What is the notion of a midpoint you have in mind? What do you mean by the continuum?

Comment: As an example, take the field $\mathbb{R}$ of reals together with the operation $\mu : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, (x,y) \mapsto \frac{x+y}{2}$ and then forget about all the structure of $\mathbb{R}$ apart from $\mu$.

Comment: Any vector space (and a divisible abelian group) will have such an operation. Do you want to recover ${\mathbb R}$ as an abelian group? As a field? As a topological space? Honestly, you have to spend more time working on an answerable formulation of your problem.

Comment: What I mean by a characterization is a categorical axiom system, i.e. a set of axioms (in this case with a single nonlogical symbol for a binary operation) with a unique model up to isomorphism, one of these isomorphic models being $\langle \mathbb{R}, \mu \rangle$. I hope this makes my question clearer.

Comment: I see: The right notion is that of  a "medial magma, or midpoint algebra". It will embed in a canonical abelian group where division by 2 is possible. I think, you just have to postulate that the median operation is compatible with a total order. Then you obtain an ordered abelian group for which you require that the order is Archimedean and complete and then use Holder's theorem. I do not know if you find this satisfactory.

Comment: I was hoping for axioms which could, in principle, be formulated in second order logic.

Comment: I think the answer is no.  Let S be a basis for R as a vector space over Q.  Let f:S->Sx2 be a bijection.  Extend f to a bijection of R and R^2 as Q-vector spaces.  Then f is also a bijection of R and R^2 as midpoint spaces, so we can't characterize the continuum using just the notion of midpoint.  Do you agree?

Comment: That is a very good point since it shows that my attempts so far went into the the wrong direction: it shows that it is impossible to define order using the notion of midpoint only; in other words: $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are isomorphic as midpoint-structures. Your comment doesn't answer my question however, although it is very helpful.

Comment: So you are just looking for a characterization of R as a midpoint structure?  Something like:  R is, up to isomorphism, the unique midpoint structure satisfying $\forall x \forall y (\exists z Mxyz) \& (\exists z Mxzy) \&(\forall z Mxyz \leftrightarrow Mzyx)$, and such that any four of $Mwxx'$, $Mwyy'$, $Mwzz'$, $Mxyz$, $Mx'y'z'$ imply the fifth?

Comment: Yes something like that would be great! I would like it to have as little “second order“ as possible, similar to the characterization with a total order, where only the completeness requires a second order axiom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me start with some formalism.

**Definition.** A *midpoint algebra* (also known as a *medial algebra*) is a set $A$ with a binary "midpoint" operation $(x,y)\mapsto x|y$ satisfying the following axioms:

1. $x|x=x$.
2. $x|y=y|x$.
3. $(u|v)|(x|y) = (u|x)|(v|y)$.
4. Horn cancelation law: $x|y = x|z  =>  y = z$. (This law is not always required, but I will assume it.)

It is a good exercise to check that every convex subset of every vector space over ${\mathbb Q}$ equipped with the midpoint operation
$$
x|y= \frac{1}{2}(x+y)
$$
is a midpoint algebra. For instance, every subinterval in ${\mathbb R}$ will have this property.

Also, every torsion-free *diadic* abelian group equipped with the midpoint operation 
$$
x|y= \frac{1}{2}(x+y)
$$
satisfies theses axioms. (For lack of a better name, I say that an abelian group $A$ is diadic if for each $a\in A$  there exists $b\in A$ such that $b+b=a$.) For instance, every subinterval in the additive group of diadic rational numbers satisfies axioms of a midpoint algebra.

In order to eliminate possibility of intervals, we assume the "doubling axiom":

5. For  each pair $x, y\in A$ there exists $z=d(x,y)\in A$ such that $y=x|z$. The cancelation law implies that such $z$ is unique.

Assume now that $A$ is a nonempty midpoint algebra satisfying axioms 1-5. Fix (at random) an element $e\in A$ and define the following binary operation:
$$
a+b:= d(0, a|b).
$$ 
If $A$ is a diadic abelian group with the neutral element $e$, it is clear that $a+b$ is the original addition operation on $A$. For a general midpoint algebra satisfying Axioms 1-5, you check that $(A, +)$ is a diadic abelian group.

However, the midpoint operation on ${\mathbb R}$ (and, more generally, on every divisible abelian group) satisfies higher divisibility properties. For instance, using divisibility by 3, one obtains (for any pair $a, b\in A$) existence of $x, y$ such that $x=a|y, y=x|b$. There are several options how to proceed from here. For instance, you can add countably many divisibility axioms for $A$ (division by each $n$, $n\in {\mathbb N}$). Assuming this set of axioms, you obtain that the abelian group $(A,+)$ defined above is torsion free and divisible. Such a group has a natural structure of a vector space over ${\mathbb Q}$ and, hence, isomorphic to a direct sum
$$
\oplus_{j\in J} {\mathbb Q}. 
$$
If the index set $J$ has cardinality of continuum, then such $A$ is isomorphic to $({\mathbb R},+)$ which, therefore, yields a characterization of ${\mathbb R}$ as a midpoint algebra, as a divisible midpoint algebra of cardinality of continuum satisfying axioms 1-5.

If you do not like having the divisibility axioms, you can proceed via an *order*: You postulate that the median algebra has a compatible total order (equivalently, the associated divisible abelian group is orderable). This is obviously expressible as a 2nd order sentence. Now, assume, in addition, that the total order is complete, i.e. every nonempty bounded (above) subset admits a least upper bound. (This is again a 2nd order sentence.) Lastly, Holder's theorem implies that every completely orderable abelian group is isomorphic to ${\mathbb R}$. This gives another characterization of   ${\mathbb R}$ as a midpoint algebra.

Comment: I like the version with the divisibility axioms, since they are first order and geometrically intuitive. Do you happen to know of an elegant axiom which could then enforce cardinality of the continuum? Something similarly intuitive as the Dedekind-Cut-Axiom?

Comment: @Larry: One option is to postulate existence of a complete order. Another (I did not think it through) is to define a (locally) compact metric topology on A where there are no isolated points. However, I do not see how to do any of this naturally, using the given structure. Maybe it is impossible, since we are effectively dealing with a vector space over Q and asking about cardinality of its basis.